# How to sort scores for high score board in a game

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting

I'm writing a game in which you can have different users. Every time you play the game you submit a score. I want to have a high-score board that show the top 10 scores of all time. For instance:

```
A:[100,200,50]
B:[400,150,320]
C:[50,245,35]
```

What I want to achieve is:

```
B 400
B 320
C 245
A 200
B 150
A 100
A 50
C 50
C 35
```

Sorting the numbers themselves isn't a big problem but how can I keep track of what number is for which player? I'm using Java and I figured maybe a HashMap would be useful but I couldn't find a solution. 
 
Basically:

1. I already have the list of scores of each player. How should I save this data for better sorting? Is HashMap a good idea?
2. What is the fastest algorithm I can use to do this task?
3. If two scores are the same the alphabetical order of player names should be checked, how can I do this?

Comment: Too many questions and too broad. Focus on one of your questions, add some code to the question and explain what your issue is with the code in more detail.

Comment: I voted to close as it's too broad. Also, sorting based on alphabetical names if scores are same isn't a fair way to judge their ranking.

Answer (score 3):

You could write a class for a score and implement `Comparable`.

```
class Score implements Comparable<Score> {

    int score;
    Player player;

    Score(int score, Player player) {
        this.score = score;
        this.player = player;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Score otherScore) {
        if (this.score > otherScore.score) {
            return 1;
        } 
        else if (this.score < otherScore.score) {
            return -1;
        }
        else {
            return this.player.name.compareTo(otherScore.player.name);
        }
    }
}
```

This way you can just save the scores in a `List` and use `Collections.sort()`.

(in the above example, I assume you have a class for `Player` with attribute `name`)

Comment: Why not use the string's `compareTo()` method? This should just be 3 lines.